# How to make gcov to read abc.pic.gcda and abc.pic.gcno files

Tags: gcov

Hi I am using `gcov` (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
When I run `gcov` I am getting errors like "cannot open graph file". (My `gcno` and `gcda` file are created with name as `abc.pic.gcda` and `abc.pic.gcno`). But when I rename these files by removing "`pic`" (`abc.gcda` and `abc.gcno`) `gcov` is working fine. My question is: how to make `gcov` to read the files which are named like `abc.pic.gcda` and `abc.pic.gcno`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have file like abc.pic.cpp
and when you compile it

> $ g++ --coverage abc.pic.cpp
>
> $ ls
>
> abc.pic.cpp  **abc.pic.gcno**  a.out

File abc.pic.gcno is created as you see. Next run binary

> $ ./a.out
>
> $ ls
>
> abc.pic.cpp  **abc.pic.gcda**  abc.pic.gcno  a.out

And run gcov:

> $ gcov abc.pic
>
> abc.gcno:cannot open graph file
>
> $ gcov abc
>
> abc.gcno:cannot open graph file

As you can see there is an error. To make it working you should provide full filename like

> $ gcov **abc.pic.cpp**
>
> File 'abc.pic.cpp'
>
> Lines executed:100.00% of 6
>
> abc.pic.cpp:creating 'abc.pic.cpp.gcov'